# Image of unit interval under $x\mapsto x-\lfloor x \rfloor$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need some help to confirm my answer is correct.

Let $x$ be a real number.

Let $f(x):=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. That is, $f(x)$ is the fractional part of $x$.

If $b-a=1$,
what is the image of $f$ on $[a,b]$?

Is the image $[0,1)$?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct.

To prove this, let $y\in[0,1)$ be arbitrary and divide into cases according to whether $y\le f(a)$ or not to find an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct, and you clearly know why it's correct.

Comment: @Daniel : Perhaps he knows the answer by intuition, and is looking for a correct proof.

Comment: The intuition and the proof are identical...

Comment: Yes, I am wondering if there's a more mathematical proof. I got the answer by just taking examples for endpoints are integers and for endpoints are not integers, and looks like [0,1) maybe be the answer.... Thanks for checking the answer for me btw~